# What means Akdama, Osafa and Yetama?

Tags: words, maseches-kesubos

I go to a gemara shiurim about Ketoubot (72a and b and 73 a and b). and these three words are said often by the Rabbi. I do not know what they means but according to their use they seems related to each other. I do not find these words in the Talmud Dictionnary neither in the hebrew dictionnary. Can you please tell me what they mean ? According to the context, it may have something to do with Bila (or Beyla, I do not know) Znout.

Comment: Hey jojo, it looks like you might have created  a new account instead of using [this existing one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/8577/jojo). You can [ask for them to be merged](/help/merging-accounts). That way, you can keep track of all of your activity here in one place.

Comment: Question is unclear. It would help a great deal if you could enter the words in Hebrew / Aramaic, link to the page(s) or, ideally, copy / paste the specific words or phrase. It is hard to decipher your transliteration.

Comment: I'm not sure why there is an off-topic VTC here. IMO it's a perfectly okay question to ask, as it's about understanding a gemara.

Comment: @Scimonster What's weird is that both accounts have the same gravatar. Did jojo choose it, or did SE give both jojos the same gravatar . . . . ?

Comment: @Shokhet It's based on either email or IP, so it would make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I'll preface this answer with the warning that I never actually learned these gemaras in Kesuvos, but I'll try to answer anyway, based on what I know about gemara learning in general.

- I think "Yetama" might actually be "Yetoma" (Hebrew: יתומה), which
  means a female orphan. The יתומה is brought up on [Kesuvos 73a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=73&format=pdf)
  for an interesting reason -- a young girl who was married by her
  father and subsequently divorced is referred to as a "יתומה בחיי
  האב," a girl "orphaned in the lifetime of her father," because after
  her divorce, her father no longer has the right to marry her off to
  another man.
- I searched in Torat Emet, and didn't find meaningful hits for the root "קדם" on the pages you mentioned, but I would suggest that the word might actually be "הקדמה," or "introduction." You might hear someone say "I'll be מקדים (*makdim*)" or "We'll make a הקדמה (*hakdama*)" before introducing a certain concept or idea.
- "Osafa" is the only one I can't place. The only thing I could think of would be "אסופי" (*asufi*). The word is translated by Jastrow as "*foundling*," (see page 89 [here](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/)) based on [Kiddushin 69a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=69&format=pdf); but as far as I could tell that word doesn't appear at all in Kesuvos.

  - user6591 suggested to me that "osafa" might really be "hosafa" (Hebrew: הוספה), which means "addition." This is a fairly commonly used word among people who learn gemara, often used "As a hosafa" or "We'll make a hosafa here," to introduce a discussion that's not really central to the topic at hand.

And finally:

- "בעילת זנות," literally translated, means "sexual intercourse for the sake of promiscuity," (i.e., not for marriage) and may be used (as it is on the top of [Kesuvos 73a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=73&format=pdf)) to refer to an argument as to whether someone who lives with a woman with nothing specific in mind, whether or not "אדם עושה בעילתו בעילת זנות," (a person *would* live with a woman and purposefully not marry her) or (conversely) "אין אדם עושה בעילתו בעילת זנות" (a person *would not* live with an unmarried woman and sin, if he could marry her with that intercourse [see [Kiddushin 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=2&format=pdf), where it says that a marriage can be made with ביאה]).

Comment: +1 i was guessing hakdama too. Kudos on yesoma. Couldn't figure that one out. Asufi too. Props.

Comment: I didn't figure out "osafa" -- I made a guess but proved myself wrong with a computer search. Thanks for the others, though :)

Comment: Maybe he means hosafa, addition. The beyla one was throwing me off. My neighbors growing up had a daughter named beyla:) took a while to figure out he meant be'ila

Comment: hosafa sounds like a good idea -- I'll edit it in. בעילת זנות wasn't hard at all, since the OP wrote "*Bila (or Beyla, I do not know) Znout*" :P

Comment: @user6591 You really need to choose a better username -- I can't keep quoting a number!! :P ( *you'll have to come to Bam to announce it, when you do* )

Comment: I like it cause it's a gematria. I just haven't figured out of what though.

Comment: @user6591 :P ....wait for [tag:mi-yodeya-series] catches up to 6591 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Transliterations are hard to decipher, esp. Aramaic transliterations. I see that you have an answer to two of the items.

"Osafa" - I am going to assume you meant אסיפא pronounced "Ah-SAY-fah" meaning "on" (or "related to" / "regarding") the ending - namely the ending of a Beriatah, Mishnah, etc. I saw that word near the end of 72a, and I am assuming this is the word that you meant. If not, please comment.

Comment: Nice catch! That hadn't occured to me, +1.